# Number in front of Google search result title

Tags: google-search

I have a blog and I've noticed that roughly half of my articles have a '1' or '2' in front of their titles when seen in Google search results. Eg:

[image]

I've search the source code and can find nothing in the meta title or og:tags that would caused this.

[Article Permalink](https://ravenectar.com/blog/tomasz-alen-koperas-paintings-will-blow-you-away)

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: impersonate googlebot and visit your site...?

Comment: What's the URL of the search result page?

Comment: @miken32 - Here is one example (first result) --- https://www.google.com/search?q=tomasz+alen+kopera&oq=tomasz+alen&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l4.3255j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=tomasz+alen+kopera+paintings+will+blow

Comment: @MarcB - How would I do that?

Comment: I've got no idea. Using that URL I see the number but if I reload or do a search myself it's not there. Sometimes that URL brings me to a search for "tomasz alen kopera paintings will blow" and sometimes it goes to a search for "tomasz alen kopera". No consistency, and no idea what the number could be for! Sorry.